# One word for the thing that other things depend on?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a have a sentence: "`A` depends on `B`", then I can describe `A` as a "dependent" (adj.). How can I describe `B` with one adjective?

Comment: "*`B` is **necessary** for `A`*"

Comment: The link to the duplicate is here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284299/single-word-for-expressing-those-which-i-am-dependent-on

Answer (score 2):

I think this relation is more normally described using nouns rather than adjectives: *Depender* A has a *dependency* on *dependee* B. Right now, I can't think of an adjective that you can use for the *dependee* in the same way that you can use *dependent* for the *depender*. Other than using *dependee* itself in this way, which is a bit awkward.

I think in computing the word *dependency* is in the process of changing its meaning so that it can actually mean dependee as well. This is because dependency relations in that context are almost always seen from the point of view of the depender, making a dependency essentially the same thing as a dependee. And in this context people universally use the term *dependency* rather than *dependee*. In a computing context this is probably the more acceptable term, even in attributive use. (E.g. "dependency project", not "dependee project".)

Answer (score 2):

If A depends on B then B is a [prerequisite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prerequisite) for A. It can be an adjective, too.