# Single word for expressing "those which I am dependent on"

Tags: single-word-requests, programming, technical

Is there any single (or near to single) word for expressing *those which I am dependent on*? I am searching for a dual term to *dependent* - **the other side of the dependency**. Something like the *interviewer - interviewee* pair.

The use case is displaying monitoring information of my web application which would list the status of all the components my application is dependent on.

What I need is a word which may be used as an attribute (ideally an adjective), such as *xxx components*, *xxx databases* etc. Then just the plain *dependencies* is not sufficient as it refers to *all the stuff* my application is dependent on.

EDIT:

Rathony suggests the word [dependee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependee) ("An agent that is depended on by a depender... Technical term, not widely used in software engineering outside of agent-oriented programming").

I found the definition of the *-ee* suffix:

1. forming nouns:
2. denoting the person affected directly or indirectly by the action of the formative verb. *"employee"*
3. denoting a person described as or concerned with. *"absentee"*
4. denoting an object of relatively smaller size. *"goatee"*

If I apply the definition to *dependence*, I cannot distinguish on which side of the relationship the "*dependee*" is.

How does that word sound to a native English (and not touched with agent-oriented programming)? Is it understood according to the above mentioned definition as someone who is "depended on"?

Comment: How about `required` or `pre-requisites`?

Comment: @DarrenYoung: Well, *required* is closely relative. But you often classify dependencies as *required dependencies* (those without which you application does not work at all) and *optional dependencies* (those nice to have for extended functionality), so it does *not* expresses the same notion.

Comment: @HonzaZidek This is not an exact match, but perhaps in the given context something like "database in use" or "component in use" could work? Another alternative would be "linked database", etc.

Comment: *Components in use* is the closest match I have seen so far. Still it's a surprise for me that English doesn't have a complementary word to *dependent* (well, my language doesn't either :) )

Comment: *requisite* or *requirement* are along the line of Steve's suggestions but seem slightly better to me.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using [***dependee***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependee) as it means:

> (programming) An agent that is depended on by a depender, the target
>   of a dependency (used in agent-oriented programming)

There is a usage note:

> Technical term, not widely used in software engineering outside of
>   agent-oriented programming but finds some use. In agent-oriented
>   programming the antonym is depender, though in general usage the
>   common term dependent is used instead. There is no common language
>   equivalent for dependee, however – other metaphors are used instead,
>   such as parent/child. The circumlocutions “A depends on B” and “B is
>   depended on by A” are much more common in general use than “A is the
>   depender, B is the dependee”.

[Wiktionary]

Comment: @HonzaZidek What happened to your example of "interviewer and interviewee"? Aren't you asking about "those which you are dependent on"? I think you are the one who is confused.

Comment: *Depender* sounds to me like someone who depends, and *dependee* sounds like the addressee of the dependency. So none of those words sound like "the one I am dependent on". It is surprising to me that your definition has it right the opposite way. (I had written my first comment before you edited your answer and added the definition.) I am going to think about the terminology. How are such words understood by common public?

Comment: @HonzaZidek I didn't edit anything but pasting the usage note just in case you might be confused with it. It is not my definition, Wiktionary's definition and I posted it as it sounds close to what you want. I advise you not to say "please read my question better". It is rude.

Comment: Yes, the *definition* sounds exactly like what I am looking for! However the words sounds *both* to me (based on their endings) like being on the same (the *dependent*) side of the dependency relationship. (N.B. Adding text to the answer is one of the possible ways of editing the answer :) )

Comment: @HonzaZidek When you find anyone who tries to help you, you say "thank you". When you find you were the one who was confused, you say "I am sorry". OK?

Comment: As I wrote, I had written my first comment BEFORE you added the definition. You were editing your answer several times very quickly so not all the edits are even in the history. As you may noticed, I have edited my comment as soon as it was clear that you had not misunderstood my request. I am sorry.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In wider usage, **patron**, **benefactor**, **supplier** or **guardian** could be appropriate options. In your more specific instance, I would suggest **Provider**:

> **1.** a person or **thing** that provides. - [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provider) (*emphasis added*)

Comment: I agree that in the wider usage all your terms fit (+1 and thanks!), but they do not fulfill my use case in the IT world.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I had a similar need to the OP. I ended up using the word *Predecessor* when referring to the other side of a dependency relationship. In my case I have dependencies between otherwise independent tasks that might be triggered out of order causing the dependent task to wait (for a limited time before throwing an error) for the task(s) it depends on to start and/or finish running. using predecessor --> dependent/successor helped me document and explain to others the mechanics of the solution in simple terms they grasped immediately.
Hope this helps someone else.