# Can an object with dependencies be called a "dependent"?

Tags: terminology, programming

Programmers spend much time discussing and resolving [object dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).

> Dependency ... [is] a state in which one object uses a function of another object.[²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency)

For example, if *A*, an object, needs a function belonging to *B*, another object, we say,

> *A* has a dependency.

According to [Dependant - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependant),

> A dependant (Commonwealth English) or dependent (American English) is a person who relies on another as a primary source of income.

Can "dependent" be used more broadly, not for a person that relies on another financially but for an object in programming that relies on another to work? That is, **can one say *B* "has a dependent"?**

Comment: That makes it two questions. To the question about programming jargon, the answer is no. To the question whether *a dependent* is used in general English, or in any other jargon except financial jargon, I don't know the answer (I'm a programmer).

Comment: Related to https://english.stackexchange.com/q/284299/73094